# Angular programmatically required validator not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have got a checkbox which displays some fields and hides some depending on its value (checked or not)

When it changes, I call a method to set validators of the previous fields to not required and I set new displayed validators to required.

```js
onSwitchCheckbox({ checked: isChecked }) {
    // small timeout to give time to DOM to render the fields because they are hidden with *ngIf="isCheckedCheckBox" (isCheckedCheckBox is a global variable)
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.isCheckedCheckBox = isChecked;
        if (isChecked) {      
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldB.setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldC.setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldA.clearValidators();
        } else {
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldB.clearValidators();
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldC.clearValidators();
            this.formGroup.controls.fieldA.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        }
    
        // update fields
        this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    }, 200);
}
```

The problem is that the fieldA stays required and the fields B and C never get required no matter if the checkbox is checked or not

What's wrong with my code ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaSharma I just reproduced it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-control-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `updateValueAndValidity` of the fieldA formControl

Try like this:

```
this.formGroup.controls.fieldA.clearValidators();
this.formGroup.controls.fieldA.updateValueAndValidity();
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-control-validators-823tqw?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Doesn't "this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();" update ALL the controls in the form ?

Comment: Moreover, it is working but doesn't update fields B and C. Do I have to do the same for all of them?